# Udev Detecting Partition like APFS FileSystem, Extracting Meta INFO

Tags: filesystems, partition, udev, apfs

Previously, I made that [CentOS 8 is not auto mounting my APFS partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596644/)

I want to discover the partition info detecting functionality, in this operative system (*I made a new CentOS installation*) I have not installed `ExFAT`, neither `NTFS` nor `APFS` File Systems.

The Linux kernel through daemons has managed to detect relevant information from `ExFAT` and `NTFS` without having a driver installed for it, but it has not detected the same information for `APFS`.

I was reading.

- [Dynamic device management with Udev, HAL, and D-Bus](https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2008/95/Hardware-Detection)
- [understanding-mount-option-nodev-and-its-use-with-usb-flash-drives](https://superuser.com/questions/538550)
- [Mounting USB disks automatically (How it works)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8159)

and read Some About of:

- `udev`   [1](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html), [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev), [3](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/udev.7.en)
- `udisks` [1](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/), [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks), [3](http://ttps://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/udisksd.8)
- `dbus`   [1](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus), [2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/D-Bus), [3](http://ttps://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/dbus/dbus-daemon.1.en)

I have a USB External SSD with 4 disk partitions.
The file system of partitions are

- `APFS`
- `ExFAT`
- `ext4`
- `NTFS`

I'm using kernel version

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64
```

I executed commands before and after my `SSD`.

**BEFORE plug the `USB External SSD`**

ls -alR /dev/ | grep -E "/dev/block:|sda|/by-|/dev/:"

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ ls -alR /dev/ | grep -E "/dev/block:|sda|/by-|/dev/:"
/dev/:
/dev/block:
/dev/disk/by-id:
/dev/disk/by-label:
/dev/disk/by-partlabel:
/dev/disk/by-partuuid:
/dev/disk/by-path:
/dev/disk/by-uuid:
/dev/dri/by-path:
/dev/input/by-id:
/dev/input/by-path:
/dev/snd/by-path:
/dev/v4l/by-id:
/dev/v4l/by-path:
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fstype,size,type,uuid,group,owner | grep sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fstype,size,type,uuid,group,owner | grep sda
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

sudo blkid | grep -v loop | grep /dev/sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ sudo blkid | grep -v loop | grep /dev/sda
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

df -aTh | grep sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ df -aTh | grep sda
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

**AFTER  plug the `USB External SSD`**

ls -alR /dev/ | grep -E "/dev/block:|sda|/by-|/dev/:"

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ ls -alR /dev/ | grep -E "/dev/block:|sda|/by-|/dev/:"
/dev/:
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     0 Jul  8 01:32 sda
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     1 Jul  8 01:32 sda1
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     2 Jul  8 01:32 sda2
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     3 Jul  8 01:32 sda3
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     4 Jul  8 01:32 sda4
brw-rw----.  1 root       disk      8,     5 Jul  8 01:32 sda5
/dev/block:
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    6 Jul  8 01:32 8:0 -> ../sda
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Jul  8 01:32 8:1 -> ../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Jul  8 01:32 8:2 -> ../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Jul  8 01:32 8:3 -> ../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Jul  8 01:32 8:4 -> ../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Jul  8 01:32 8:5 -> ../sda5
/dev/disk/by-id:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ata-KINGSTON_SA400S37960G_50026B76830DD5C0-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 wwn-0x50026b76830dd5c0-part5 -> ../../sda5
/dev/disk/by-label:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 EFI -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ExFAT -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 EXT4 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 NTFS -> ../../sda5
/dev/disk/by-partlabel:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 EFI\x20System\x20Partition -> ../../sda1
/dev/disk/by-partuuid:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 57527f55-2ebb-4624-8a05-0253c1ea744b -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 759e06ee-9a30-4e51-81a4-41ee8ebfecd3 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 93480588-2497-4c06-8aff-5d218f6a5260 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 a0c6c246-9f36-43f2-acd6-fd6214852fa1 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 b26baae4-6b53-4358-b707-18bfde5679f4 -> ../../sda5
/dev/disk/by-path:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   9 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part4 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part5 -> ../../sda5
/dev/disk/by-uuid:
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 5F00-07F7 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 67E3-17ED -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 AA00430E0042E145 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  10 Jul  8 01:32 ce8c8777-e073-4f0a-8faa-361c6136154f -> ../../sda3
/dev/dri/by-path:
/dev/input/by-id:
/dev/input/by-path:
/dev/snd/by-path:
/dev/v4l/by-id:
/dev/v4l/by-path:
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fstype,size,type,uuid,group,owner | grep sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,fstype,size,type,uuid,group,owner | grep sda
sda                                                                         894.3G disk                                      disk  root
├─sda1                                                  EFI        vfat       200M part 67E3-17ED                            disk  root
├─sda2                                                                      223.5G part                                      disk  root
├─sda3       /run/media/joseluisbz/EXT4                 EXT4       ext4     223.5G part ce8c8777-e073-4f0a-8faa-361c6136154f disk  root
├─sda4                                                  ExFAT      exfat    223.5G part 5F00-07F7                            disk  root
└─sda5                                                  NTFS       ntfs     223.5G part AA00430E0042E145                     disk  root
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

sudo blkid | grep -v loop | grep sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ sudo blkid | grep -v loop | grep sda
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="759e06ee-9a30-4e51-81a4-41ee8ebfecd3"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="EXT4" UUID="ce8c8777-e073-4f0a-8faa-361c6136154f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="93480588-2497-4c06-8aff-5d218f6a5260"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="ExFAT" UUID="5F00-07F7" TYPE="exfat" PARTUUID="a0c6c246-9f36-43f2-acd6-fd6214852fa1"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="NTFS" UUID="AA00430E0042E145" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b26baae4-6b53-4358-b707-18bfde5679f4"
/dev/sda2: PARTUUID="57527f55-2ebb-4624-8a05-0253c1ea744b"
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

df -aTh | grep sda

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ df -aTh | grep sda
/dev/sda3       ext4             220G   61M  208G   1% /run/media/joseluisbz/EXT4
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

udevadm info

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda1
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda2
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda3
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda4
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm info --query=path -n /dev/sda5
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

**RESULTS**

Checking in the `/dev/disk/by-label:` and `/dev/disk/by-uuid:` directory lists, the partition `sda2` is hidden or is not detected.

**udevadm monitor**

```
[joseluisbz@centos dev]$ udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[77069.521440] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
KERNEL[77069.522640] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[77069.522813] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[77069.522821] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[77069.522833] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[77069.522846] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
UDEV  [77069.526612] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
UDEV  [77069.527772] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [77069.528281] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [77069.528922] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [77069.529477] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [77069.530400] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
KERNEL[77070.560967] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[77070.560994] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[77070.561008] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[77070.561023] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[77070.561032] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[77070.561155] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[77070.561278] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [77070.562061] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[77070.562354] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [77070.562884] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [77070.563104] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [77070.563500] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [77070.563861] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [77070.567553] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [77070.568227] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [77070.568461] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[77070.569086] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[77070.569104] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
KERNEL[77070.569118] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
KERNEL[77070.569130] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3 (block)
KERNEL[77070.569141] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4 (block)
KERNEL[77070.569151] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
UDEV  [77070.592807] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [77070.675152] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda3 (block)
UDEV  [77070.675266] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda4 (block)
UDEV  [77070.675361] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [77070.675630] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda5 (block)
UDEV  [77070.685401] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda2 (block)
^C[joseluisbz@centos dev]$
```

[Supporting me in this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/udev-for-device-detection-management-in-linux/) and **Executing the command `udevadm info /dev/sda(#:number partition)`**

/dev/sda2

```
E: ID_FS_... (REALLY THIS TYPE INFORMATION IS MISSING)
```

/dev/sda3

```
E: ID_FS_LABEL=EXT4
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=EXT4
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ext4
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=ce8c8777-e073-4f0a-8faa-361c6136154f
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=ce8c8777-e073-4f0a-8faa-361c6136154f
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
```

/dev/sda4

```
E: ID_FS_LABEL=ExFAT
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=ExFAT
E: ID_FS_TYPE=exfat
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=5F00-07F7
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=5F00-07F7
E: ID_FS_VERSION=1.0
```

/dev/sda5

```
E: ID_FS_LABEL=NTFS
E: ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=NTFS
E: ID_FS_TYPE=ntfs
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_UUID=AA00430E0042E145
E: ID_FS_UUID_ENC=AA00430E0042E145
```

<strike>**Lacking adaptation (development) of Udev in order to detect the new type of APFS file system ?** *, I think that yes*.</strike>

<strike>**How likely would AFPS partition detection be included in Kernel version 5.8?**</strike>

<strike>**I would like to get my hands on the code where should I start?** *apart from [blog1](https://blog.cugu.eu/post/apfs/) [blog2](https://www.ntfs.com/apfs-structure.htm) [pdf1](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/media/FOR518-Reference-Sheet.pdf)*.</strike>

**How [`blkid`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) is interacting with these (services) daemons?**

I was trying to extract metainfo from `APFS`

```
[joseluisbz@centos Documents]$ sudo hexdump -s 0 -n 16384 -C /dev/sda2
00000000  df 82 aa 66 bf 6e 98 66  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...f.n.f........|
00000010  75 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |u...............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  80 0e 7e 03 00 00 00 00  |NXSB......~.....|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  7c 10 fe 73 2a cb 41 b4  |........|..s*.A.|
00000050  9f 7a ff c9 d6 3e 7f ab  1a 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.z...>..........|
00000060  76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 01 00 00 20 6c 00 00  |v........... l..|
00000070  45 81 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |E...............|
00000080  8c 00 00 00 49 01 00 00  8a 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |....I...........|
00000090  43 01 00 00 06 00 00 00  0f 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |C...............|
000000a0  10 7e 09 00 00 00 00 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.~..............|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 64 00 00 00  02 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....d...........|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000003d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e4 07 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000520  01 00 04 00 08 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000530  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000560  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 74 19 cf 50 04 05 00  |.........t..P...|
00000570  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000  9e 47 b2 7f 8d a4 4d 00  01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.G....M.........|
00001010  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  11 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |0...............|
00001020  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001040  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00001060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 90 0f 00 00  |................|
00001070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002000  9e 6d 33 59 59 cb 0f 17  05 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.m3YY...........|
00002010  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 80 09 00 00 00  |0...............|
00002020  07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 40 02 20 00 30 0d  |..........@. .0.|
00002030  00 00 10 00 08 00 08 00  10 00 10 00 00 00 08 00  |................|
00002040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002270  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 10 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002280  79 58 01 00 00 00 00 00  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |yX......0.......|
00002290  03 c2 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000022a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002fc0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  9e 97 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00002fd0  ff ff 08 00 00 00 00 00  0e 00 00 00 00 10 00 00  |................|
00002fe0  10 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  |................|
00002ff0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00003000  97 e1 f1 56 27 4a c3 21  0f 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...V'J.!........|
00003010  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |0...............|
00003020  00 10 00 00 00 80 00 00  7e 00 00 00 fb 01 00 00  |........~.......|
00003030  80 0e 7e 03 00 00 00 00  fd 06 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..~.............|
00003040  0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  93 f3 7c 03 00 00 00 00  |..........|.....|
00003050  08 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00003060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003080  80 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00003090  01 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  24 15 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........$.......|
000030a0  01 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  5d 82 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........].......|
000030b0  21 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |!l..............|
000030c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000030e0  05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000030f0  9e 97 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00003100  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |0...............|
00003110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003140  01 00 0f 00 d8 09 00 00  e0 09 00 00 e8 09 00 00  |................|
00003150  01 00 00 00 d8 09 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00003160  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000039d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  30 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........0.......|
000039e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 02 00 03 00 04 00  |................|
000039f0  05 00 06 00 07 00 08 00  09 00 0a 00 0b 00 0c 00  |................|
00003a00  0d 00 0e 00 0f 00 ff ff  21 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........!l......|
00003a10  22 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  23 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |"l......#l......|
00003a20  24 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  25 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |$l......%l......|
00003a30  26 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  27 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |&l......'l......|
00003a40  28 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  29 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(l......)l......|
00003a50  2a 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  2b 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |*l......+l......|
00003a60  2c 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  2d 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |,l......-l......|
00003a70  2e 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  2f 6c 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.l....../l......|
00003a80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00004000
[joseluisbz@centos Documents]$
```

**The Apple question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396301**

Comment: Currently, your question contains more than one issue. Please split it into several individual questions so they can be answered one by one; as you probably know, you can still link these among each other using the URL in the "share" link.

Comment: Now, I removed the opinion questions.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all userspace tools use (lib)blkid (from util-linux) to detect filesystems on block devices. UDisks uses data from UDev and UDev runs blkid in its rules.

Kernel has nothing to do with this, you don't need kernel module to detect filesystem signature (blkid reads data directly from the disk/block device and compares signatures (binary data) against its internal database). Kernel module (or fuse module) is needed only for actually mounting the device.

Support for APFS [was added in util-linux 2.33](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/084f092a62f8767998d8b00222eb14f3ec94e8b6) and [CentOS 8 has only 2.32](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/util-linux-2.32.1-22.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) so without manually upgrading util-linux UDisks can't automount your APFS drive.

Comment: Thanks!, Is there procedure in order to test it?